# The number of controls in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, forms, controls, limit

A question out of curiosity.

Is there a recommended limit to the number of controls in one form? How many is too many?

Comment: When the form looks messy, that is too many.

Comment: Depends if you are considering user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is VB then the limit is `256`
But even beyong that you can use `control arrays`.
and "How many is too many depends on your forms size"
its always good to use controls as low as possible in number to make the form look good and tidy.